# Springboot (1.5.10) placeholder property of array element

Tags: spring-boot

How can I use a Springboot placeholder property of a previously defined array element?

For example, here is a sample application.yml file.

```
application:
  array:
    - id: element1
      description: Element one of the property array
    - id: element2
      description: Element two of the property array
  placeholder-test:
    - element-placeholder: ${application.array[0]}
```

This sample does not work when I test it out. Is there a workaround or some other syntax I could be using to get this to work?